# LibTorch IValue::to<T>()

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch, torchscript

I have a Python PyTorch Vision model, `class MobileNetV2(nn.Module)`, that has the following attribute:
`self.features = torch.nn.Sequential(*features)`, and I want to access `features` from C++ after loading it from the JIT API so I can mutate it.

```cpp
torch::jit::script::Module mobilenetv2 = torch::jit::load("mobilenetv2.pt");
auto features = mobilenetv2.attr("features").to<torch::nn::Sequential>(); // IValue::to<T> fails to compile
```

From the error message, I see that it tried to delegate to:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T generic_to(IValue ivalue, _fake_type<T>) {
  using ElemType = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type::element_type;
  return std::move(ivalue).toCustomClass<ElemType>();
}
```

And of course `Sequential` does not have an `element_type` typedef.

What is the correct way to extract the type from the `IValue`?